# Website-scraping , robot-identification

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

Are there websites which identify it as a script that is accessing it , inspite of changing the User-Agent headers which I assume is like this and gives an error.

```
import urllib,urllib2
req_headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers = req_headers)
html = req.open(url)
```

If yes , then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  For starters, look at your complete header when browsing the web using a tool like Firebug.  You'll notice normal browsers provide a lot of information such as languages accepted that is not provided by `urllib`.  So a website might check for the presence of other header information.

Another trick would be to include a 1x1 pixel image on a page and check if the client requested the image file.  If not, then the client is using either a text only browser (like [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/)) or is actually a script.  I think JavaScript can also be used to look for the presence of a mouse.

Generally, it's a game of cat and mouse.  One alternative to `urllib` is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).  Selenium will launch a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your User Agent is pretty incomplete and easily detectable as fake.

I describe some robot detection techniques in my answer to [Hunting cheaters in a voting competition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333054).